# Removing hover effect form clicked element

Tags: html, css

I have a one question: how I can remove :hover effect on navigation object that is currently clicked?

```css
  .navigation-buttons li a {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #59114d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: background 0.5s, font-weight 0.5s, color 0.5s ease-out;
}

.navigation-buttons li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navigation-buttons li a:hover,
.navigation-buttons li a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #59114d;
  color: #edf2f4;
```

```html
<ul class="navigation-buttons rectangular2">
  <li class="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">galeria</a></li>
  <li class="about"><a href="about.html">o mnie </a></li>
  <li class="offer"><a href="#">oferta</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do it just with CSS? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in **CSS** by simply removing the `hover` style you have applied to your your `navigation-buttons element on this line of code:

```
.navigation-buttons li a:hover,
```

You can test it here:

```css
  .navigation-buttons li a {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #59114d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: background 0.5s, font-weight 0.5s, color 0.5s ease-out;
}

.navigation-buttons li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navigation-buttons li a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #59114d;
  color: #edf2f4;
```

```html
<ul class="navigation-buttons rectangular2">
  <li class="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">galeria</a></li>
  <li class="about"><a href="about.html">o mnie </a></li>
  <li class="offer"><a href="#">oferta</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can read more about the `hover` style [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specyfic enough: I wish to have :hover effect on every <li> except for one that is currently clicked - when I'm watching gallery for example and move my mouse to check out another subpage I want :hover to work except for gallery subpage. Thanks

Comment: @Weeanerd Yeah it sounded like you didn't want the hover effect on. Well `hover` by definition will only be activated when your mouse is over the element with the `hover` style. Therefore you can't apply `hover` to all the elements of the list since they aren't all selected at once. What you can do is create a style that is similar to hover for each list element, then remove that style when you hover over an element

Comment: Create similar style similar to hover? What do you mean? Can you show some example?

Comment: @Weeanerd I meant that you cannot hover over all the elements at once. Therefore what you can do is write a style for all elements of the list which will look like all elements are being hovered (when actually they are not), and when you actually hover over an element and click it, that elements wtyle will look like it is not being hovered while all the others will still be. if that doesn't make sense, then I don't really understand what you trying to do. Do you have an online example of what you are to do? Maybe it will be help me understand better so I can help you

Comment: It makes sense now actually, I've just done it and it will stay that way. Thanks